# Compare two string variables in if statement that includes zeros

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

This is a bit of a tricky one to explain but I've never come across this before so I've got no idea how to properly approach it. I'm writing a web app that when a form is submitted, it takes two values, the current value and the submitted value.

When the form is submitted, it **checks that the new value is not the same as the current value**. If that is true, then go through the rest of the process. This is so I'm not updating the database with values that already exist in there.

Problem is I have an assigned to select box. One of the options is unassigned which has a value of 0. But in the following if statement, zero is not treated as a proper value and thus fails the check.

```
( $newtaskassignee != $taskassignid ) { ... do something ... }
```

So when `$newtaskassignee` is 0, the following if statement should be true and carry on what is inside the immediate curly brackets.

However in this statement, zero is ignored and doesn't pass the check. How can I change this so it **accepts numbers from 1 to 9 including 0**. This checks user IDs so they could be anything so I can't select a range as it increments by 1 per user obviously.

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($newtaskassignee); var_dump($taskassignid)`?

Comment: Don't forget about PHP loose type juggling. Did you try `$newtaskassignee !== $taskassignid`?

Comment: That's what I was thinking sjagr, hence my question ;)

Comment: Hm, the var_dump returns 0 (zero, as it should) and adding a second equal sign doesn't seem to do anything different.

Comment: and what's the type of the variable? `var_dump` also returns that

Comment: var_dump states that it's string.

Comment: Oh darn it. It turns out the wrong variable was being using so it was being overwritten by the time it got to the if statement check. All fixed now. Sorry for wasting your time guys. I spent ages looking over it and thought I was using incorrect syntax, not a rookie mistake...

Answer (score 0):

```
( $newtaskassignee !== $taskassignid )
```

The extra = will do an exact match and won't take 0 as false but 0.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP has not strong types, there are two sets of equality operators. 
one set that focus on **value only** : **==** and **!=**
and
one that focus on **value AND type** : **===** and **!==**

When you compare '' and 0, == will return true as, for PHP, these are same values.
So you may use === comparison operator to ensure that both operands are same value AND type.

Have a look on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php, and particularly the difference between "equal" and "identical".

Hope this help